# Dynamically Assign Column Delimiter to Flat file source in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Goal  - To import multiple flat files(may be 1000's or more every day) with different column delimiter

I was trying to dynamically assign the column delimiter to a flat file source connection manager in SSIS. (It seems that is not possible since there is no in-built function(Column Delimiter) in SSIS to dynamically assign values) Also I can't use "Bulk Insert Task" to load different flat files since I need to include a derived column in the data flow.

How can I achieve this in the data flow/data flow plus(cozyroc) task ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do all of the files have the same meta data?

Comment: Can you provide a data sample? Are the columns simple? Do you know the position of the first delimiter (for example, is the first non-numeric value? or in the 2nd position?

Comment: @TabAlleman- No each file has different metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable via 3rd party SSIS component (DataFlow plus task) where we can define the column delimter as a variable. Please see below screen shot.

[image]